# Error using Meteor.loginWithPassword

Tags: meteor

I am using "meteor.loginWithPassword" in my website for logging in but in the matter of fact I always get the error : "Match failed". 
I do not find the reason why?
I have the user I am testing in my Database. I read somewhere that it is because one of the fields are empty, but this is not the reason. 
I don`t know what should I check?

```
Template.login.events({
'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = $('[name=username]').val();
    var password = $('[name=password]').val();

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

});

Comment: If you `console.log(username, password)` just before the call to `loginWithPassword`, do you get two non-empty strings? If you don't, it could be that your jquery selectors are just incorrect.

Comment: @DavidWeldon's suggestion will help once you know what values are permitted via my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

## How to understand the error

When you're getting a `Match` error that's ultimately from the `'meteor/check'` library.

So what you want to solve is "what `Match` conditions does the `Meteor.loginWithPassword` method expect". This will tell you what argument values will be permitted at runtime.

To answer that question you can look here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password where the code that sets up that method is defined.

> NOTE: code references from here on arbitrarily reference version 2.5.8 to keep line references. However you could search under the version your code is at in essentially the same place

More specifically you're interested in the `check` call here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%402.5.8/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L170,#L173.

## Bonus Round

It's worth noting that even if you were crawling the source code and found where `Meteor.loginWithPassword` is defined here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%402.5.8/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L33 it wouldn't be super obvious that the method call there gets picked up by the handler here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%402.5.8/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L166.

As it turns out the handlers match on the shape of arguments not the name .